# Default user when Authentication is turned off (Angular)

Tags: angular, http, authentication

I have a project with Authentication but now it's turned off. I need to set Admin user as a default and don't check it from base when Authentication doesn't work. I know that should make a check and set a default user in `get(): Observable<User> {}` but don't understand how.
Would be really grateful for any help!
Here's my code:

authentication.server.ts

```
import { User } from '../shared/models/user';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  get(): Observable<User> {
    return  this.http.get<User>('api/user')
  }
}
```

User.ts

```
import { UserRole } from '../user-role.enum';
export class Role {
  constructor(id: number, name: UserRole) {}
}

export class User {
  constructor(
    role: Role = null
}
```

User-role.enum.ts

```
export enum UserRole {
  Admin = 'Admin',
  Manager = 'Manager',
  User = 'User'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About your problem, first, your user class must point to the UserRole enum and be like this:

```
    // make sure to put you directory and the name of the object
    import { UserRole } from './../enum/User-role.enum';

    export class User {
      constructor(
        id: number = null,
        firstName: string = '',
        lastName: string = '',
        email: string = '',
   //the type of role must be te name of object import between {UserRole}
        role: UserRole = UserRole.Admin
    }
```

second, when you create some user you can do like bellow:

a) declaration:

```
private userAdmin: User = new User();
```

b) use in some method:

```
userAdmin.role = UserRole.Admin
```

Finnaly, make sure to point correctly to your enum directory on the import of class user.

And I think that's all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried something similar but still have some issues. As I understood I need to make some check in `get(): Observable<User> {}` and if `http.get()` can't get the user and status is **Unauthorized** - put **Admin** as a default. And I'm actually don't understand how to return my Admin user in this  `get(): Observable<User> {}` function

Answer (score 0):

Your service is ok, but you have do this on the component that will use this service.

On the component, first create a user to receive the data:

```
public returnedUser: User = new User(); // public if you want to use on template
```

Then, put this code in the ngInit of your component to use the the service and subscribe it to receive the information from API.

```
this.AuthenticationService.get()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        data = this.returnedUser = data;
      });
```

finally, you will get you user inside the object returnedUser.

i think this is what you need.